# Crystal CASE Datediff range using getdate

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, case, datediff

Trying to convert the following SQL into a Case statement in CR:

```
CASE 
WHEN Datediff(dd, getdate(), THS.Q_LoanInfo.DueDate) BETWEEN - 59 AND - 30 THEN '1-[Delq 30-59]' 
WHEN Datediff(dd, getdate(), THS.Q_LoanInfo.DueDate) BETWEEN - 179 AND - 60 THEN '2-[Delq 60-179]' 
WHEN Datediff(dd, getdate(), THS.Q_LoanInfo.DueDate) BETWEEN - 359 AND - 180 THEN '3-[Delq 180-359]' 
WHEN Datediff(dd, getdate(), THS.Q_LoanInfo.DueDate) < - 360 THEN '5-[Delq 360+]' ELSE NULL
```

Not sure if CASE or IF/THEN is better suited for this.  Replaced `'dd' (not recognized in CR?)` with `DAY`.  Also replaced `Getdate()` with `CurrentDate` and `BETWEEN` with `TO`.

```
if Datediff(Day,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},currentdate)  to  - 59 AND - 30 THEN '1-[Delq 30-59]' else
if Datediff(Day,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate) to - 179 AND - 60 THEN '2-[Delq 60-179]' else
if Datediff(Day,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate) to - 359 AND - 180 THEN '3-[Delq 180-359]' else
if Datediff(Day,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate)   <=  - 360 THEN '5-[Delq 360+]' ELSE 'NULL'
```

Currently getting the following error with this: **"Not enough arguments have been given to this function"**.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  This is supposed to populate date range buckets.

Comment: what is `[Delq 30-59]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Datediff(Day,currentdate,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate}) 

   Case  30 to 59    : '1-[Delq 30-59]'
   Case  60 to 179   : '2-[Delq 60-179]' 
   Case  180 to 359  : '3-[Delq 180-359]' 
   Case  >= 360      : '5-[Delq 360+]' 
   Default           : 'NULL'
;
```

Comment: Makes sense but still giving me the "Not enough arguments have been given to this function" error.  Also, didn't like the >=360 but I can add in a range there to make that part work for time being.

Comment: whups I missed the obvious error  Select Datediff('d',currentdate,{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate}) ... replace Day with 'd'

Answer (score 0):

For Syntax always check online help and then try to write formula

try this:

```
if (Datediff("d",{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},currentdate)  in (- 59 to - 30 ))THEN '1-[Delq 30-59]' 
else
if (Datediff("d",{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate) in (- 179 to - 60)) THEN '2-[Delq 60-179]' 
else
if Datediff("d",{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate) in (- 359 to - 180 ))THEN '3-[Delq 180-359]' 
else
if Datediff("d",{Q_LoanInfo.DueDate},CurrentDate)   <=  - 360) THEN '5-[Delq 360+]' 
ELSE 'NULL'
```